# Invariant inheritance problem

Tags: c#, casting, contravariance

I'm trying to implement a strategy pattern to allow me to allow me to apply some "benefit" to an "account". In the code below, I can't add my implementation of an interface to a dictionary expecting the interface. I think it's some kind of contravariance problem, but it feels like I should be able to do this:

**EDIT:**
Since the answer seems to be that it's just not possible, any suggestions on how to achieve what I'm going for here?

```
void Main()
{
    var provider = new BenefitStrategyProvider();

    var freeBenefit = new FreeBenefit();

    var strategy = provider.GetStrategy(freeBenefit);

    strategy.ApplyBenefit(freeBenefit, new Account());

}

public class BenefitStrategyProvider
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IBenefitStrategy<BenefitBase>> _strategies = new Dictionary<Type, IBenefitStrategy<BenefitBase>>();

    public BenefitStrategyProvider()
    {
        /* Why can't I add this? */
        _strategies.Add(typeof(FreeBenefit), new FreeBenefitStrategy());
    }

    public IBenefitStrategy<BenefitBase> GetStrategy(BenefitBase benefit)
    {
        return _strategies[benefit.GetType()];
    }

}

public class Account {}

public abstract class BenefitBase
{
    public string BenefitName {get;set;}    
}

public class FreeBenefit : BenefitBase {}

public interface IBenefitStrategy<T> where T: BenefitBase
{
    void ApplyBenefit(T benefit, Account account);
}

public class FreeBenefitStrategy : IBenefitStrategy<FreeBenefit>
{
    public void ApplyBenefit(FreeBenefit benefit, Account account)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Free Benefit applied");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tejs yes I am using .net 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDITED - The formatting engine had removed everything in `<angled brackets>`, which made it rather impossible to understand. Sorry if this was confusing!*

`FreeBenefitStrategy` implements `IBenefitStrategy<FreeBenefit>`. It can apply only `FreeBenefits`, not any other kind of benefit. It is not an `IBenefitStrategy<BenefitBase>`, so you can't put it in a collection of those. Logically, `IBenefiteStrategy` could be contravariant in `BenefitBase`, but this doesn't help you here - an `IBenefitStrategy<BenefitBase>` claims to be able to apply *all* kinds of benefits, so an `IBenefitStrategy<BenefitBase>` is-an `IBenefitStrategy<FreeBenefit>`, but the converse is not true - an `IBenefitStrategy<FreeBenefit>` cannot apply any `BenefitBase`.

I don't think there's any way to have a heterogenous collection like you want without using type-casting. If you think about it, there's no method that you can invoke on both an `IBenefitStrategy<FreeBenefit>` and an `IBenefitStrategy<ExpensiveBenefit>` beyond those that they share from object, so it makes sense that a variable of type object is the only thing that can point to either. If you want to keep them in the same dictionary, you'll need to make it a `Dictionary<Type, object>`. You could change `GetStrategy` to be generic and apply appropriate type-casting, but do be careful when looking up your dictionary - think what will happen if the object passed in is of a sub-class of `FreeBenefit`.

Answer (score 1):

See: [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

```
How can I create variant generic interfaces and delegates myself?

The out keyword marks a type parameter as covariant, and the in keyword marks it as contravariant. The two most important rules to remember:
    You can mark a generic type parameter as covariant if it is used only as a method return type and is not used as a type of formal method parameters.
    And vice versa, you can mark a type as contravariant if it is used only as a type of formal method parameters and not used as a method return type.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add out T to your interface:

```
public interface IBenefitStrategy<in T>
```

Comment: That end's up giving me this error: Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'IBenefitStrategy<T>.ApplyBenefit(T, UserQuery.Account)'. 'T' is covariant.

Comment: That's because it should be `in T`, not `out T`. `T` here is a type variable, and your interface only "takes in" objects of type `T` and never "outputs" them, so this is a model citizen for contravariance.

Comment: @Paul Z, but when I make it in T, I can't add the implementation!